# TDS Throws a NullReferenceException when auto-generating models

Tags: tds

Every so often, TDS will throw a NullReferenceException while attempting to generate code for sync'ed Sitecore Items.

Here is the error from the output log:

> Generating file C:\Path\To\GeneratedCode.cs 
>   ERROR : on line 0 column 0 of file C:\Path\To\Code\Generate\Template.tt 
>   Running transformation: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating4EBD01F908618B2878D40309BB467CB0AF91462B3C9AA05AF72392556DFEBB765829C5679F118E27F30F9B93397F2511CA0D88F187AE7DFEBE5EEE255C5A7A49.GeneratedTextTransformation.<>c.b__5_2(SitecoreTemplate t)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__16`2.MoveNext()
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating4EBD01F908618B2878D40309BB467CB0AF91462B3C9AA05AF72392556DFEBB765829C5679F118E27F30F9B93397F2511CA0D88F187AE7DFEBE5EEE255C5A7A49.GeneratedTextTransformation.GetFieldsForTemplate(SitecoreTemplate item, Boolean includeBases)
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating4EBD01F908618B2878D40309BB467CB0AF91462B3C9AA05AF72392556DFEBB765829C5679F118E27F30F9B93397F2511CA0D88F187AE7DFEBE5EEE255C5A7A49.GeneratedTextTransformation.TransformText()

This is an intermittent bug that happens, most commonly, after I get latest from my branch.  It resolves itself up after a few computer restarts; however, if there's a way to fully prevent it or to clear a cache somewhere to fix it when it comes up, I would prefer such a solution.

Comment: Are you changing branches while Visual Studio is open? I have seen issues with that.

Comment: That tends to be the trigger when this happens, yes.  So it feels like a caching issue and am hoping to find where/how to resolve when I forget to close the solution prior to changing branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have already solved this issue by now however for those facing this issue, you can follow these steps.

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task
   Manager)
2. Delete the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0\ComponentModelCache
   directory
3. Restart Visual Studio.

Source: https://github.com/Codealike/Codealike-KnowledgeBase/blob/master/clear-visual-studio-component-cache.md

Took me few hours to try everything and found the above trick fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have sometimes seen issues where TDS gets out of date (especially when switching between git branches).

I have always been able to resolve them by right-clicking on the TDS project and selecting **Re-Generate Code for all Items**:

[image: Context menu with regenerate code for all items highlighted]

Comment: The error I posted occurs when I select Re-Generate Code for all Items